# Convert Perl string to json array

Tags: json, string, perl

I am attempting to write a Perl script that will run on a Centos 6 host. This script will run a shell command that queries our AWS interface like this:

```
my $json = `aws ec2 describe-instances`;
```

This query will return a JSON object but I belive my issue is that it is actually being stored as a string in $output and not actually in a JSON object.

I am trying the following code:

```
# Get each instance
my $json = `aws ec2 describe-instances`;

# Decode AWS json result
my $decoded = decode_json $json;

# Find reference type
print "Reference type: " . ref $decoded,"\n";

# Loop through each EC2 instance
print $decoded -> {Reservations} . "\n";
```

When I execute this code I get the following message:

```
Reference type: HASH
ARRAY(0xa774b0)
```

Can anyone help me with this? I have been googling and messing with this for over a whole day now :(

Below is an example of the string that is stored in $output although in the real output there would be multiple instances:

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "OwnerId": "82XXXXXXX043",
            "ReservationId": "r-0XXXXXXXXXXX",
            "Groups": [],
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "XXXXX"
                    },
                    "PublicDnsName": "XXX",
                    "RootDeviceType": "XXXXXXX",
                    "State": {
                        "Code": XXX,
                        "Name": "stopped"
                    },
                    "EbsOptimized": XXXX,
                    "LaunchTime": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    "VpcId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "StateTransitionReason": "UXXXXXXXXXX",
                    "InstanceId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "ImageId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "PrivateDnsName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "KeyName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "SubnetId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "InstanceType": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Status": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "MacAddress": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "SourceDestCheck": XXXXXXXXXX,
                            "VpcId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Description": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "Primary": XXXXXXXXXX,
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                                }
                            ],
                            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                            "Attachment": {
                                "Status": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                "DeviceIndex": 01234,
                                "DeleteOnTermination": XXXXXXXXXX,
                                "AttachmentId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                "AttachTime": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                            },
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                    "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                                },
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                    "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                                },
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                    "GroupId": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                                }
                            ],
                            "SubnetId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "OwnerId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": XXXXXXXXXX,
                    "Placement": {
                        "Tenancy": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                        "GroupName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                        "AvailabilityZone": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                    },
                    "Hypervisor": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "Status": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": XXXXXXXXXX,
                                "VolumeId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                                "AttachTime": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Architecture": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "StateReason": {
                        "Message": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                        "Code": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                    },
                    "IamInstanceProfile": {
                        "Id": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                        "Arn": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                    },
                    "RootDeviceName": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "VirtualizationType": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        },
                        {
                            "Value": "XXXXXXXXXX",
                            "Key": "XXXXXXXXXX"
                        }
                    ],
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": XXXXXXXXXX
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: your example looks like a hash, not like an array.

Comment: *"my issue is that it is actually being stored as a string in `$output` and not actually in a JSON object"*. What do you imagine a *"JSON object"* to be? *JSON* is *JavaScript Object Notation* and is, by definition, a string of text. It is the job of the `JSON` module to convert between a JSON string and the data structure that it represents.

Comment: There is no variable `$output`. Do you mean `$json`?

Comment: You need to tell us what you actually want to do with this data. The reference type is not very relevant here. When you call `decode_json`, you turn the string of JSON into a Perl data structure. The hierarchy inside that structure maps exactly to JSON. In your code you say you _Loop through each EC2 instance_, but you don't loop. You print the value behind the key `Reservations`. That's an array reference, and if you print that, it stringifies to `ARRAY(0xdeadb33f)`. That's expected. If you want to turn this back into JSON, you need to tell Perl that. `encode_json` sounds reasonable.

Comment: Or use Data::Dumper or Data::Printer to inspect the Perl data structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON starts with a `{` so the error is quite correct. You don't have an array reference, you have a hash reference.

Try `print ref $decoded,"\n"` and it'll tell you what type of reference you have.

Try `$decoded -> {Reservations}` or just print the whole thing with `Data::Dumper`:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $decoded;
```

Comment: So it works then. Problem sorted. Your hash dereference gets you an array. You can iterate the array as you wish. Please don't amend your question to ask something else - that invalidates any answers that you're getting, which are supposed to be for other people to refer to.

Comment: I guess I am not sure how to loop through the hash. So $decoded is now an array that I can loop through? I will try that...

Comment: No. `$decoded -> {Reservations}` is an array reference. You can iterate that with `for my $reservation ( @{$decoded->{Reservations}} ) { ` and then you'll find that `$reservation` is another hash reference

Answer (score 3):

You've successfully converted the JSON string into a Perl data structure. Looks like you're falling down because you don't know how to manipulate Perl data structures. Reading the [perldsc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) manual page would probably help there.

I see that `$decoded->{Reservations}` is an array reference. So you'll be able to walk that array with code like:

```
foreach my $reservation (@{ $decoded->{Reservations} }) {
  # Do something useful with $reservation
}
```

Alternatively, you might consider using a library like [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws) to handle your AWS interaction.